# FastAPI: Как отобразить custom exception class в openapi?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Подскажите пожалуйста как отобразить пользовательские классы ошибок в документации open api?
Такие, как: HTTPValidationError, ValidationError, только пользовательские.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]